# How to combine the cell removing empty values in column in excel

Tags: google-sheets

[image][image]

Need to get that output : Empty cells should be removed and need to get all that in 2 columns without empty cells.

Comment: What have you tried? This has been asked and answered on this forum for Excel. I'd expect Sheets to have a similar solution.

Comment: i have tried COCATENATE it was not coming i have showed output just explain for better understanding can you help me out. @RonRosenfeld

Comment: In Excel, something like `=IF($H$3:$I$9="",$J$3:$K$9,$H$3:$I$9)`. Must be an equivalent in Sheets.

Comment: it's working but what if i had more rows like

Comment: If you have more rows, merely change the range references.

Answer (score 1):

try in GS:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:B=""; C:D; A:B))
```

---

```
={QUERY(FLATTEN(A1:G), "where Col1 is not null skipping 2"),
  QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(A1:G), "where Col1 is not null offset 1"), "skipping 2")}
```

[image]

Comment: it was working fine with this but what if there are 10 to 15 columns what should be needed to do.